# Skype won't open: "We can't open Skype. You are already signed in on this computer..."

Tags: linux, skype

I get the following message when trying to sign into skype after my Ubuntu machine hasn't been shut down properly and skype was running:

"We can't open Skype. You are already signed in on this computer. Please sign out and try again."

Comment: Off-topic, belongs to http://superuser.com

Comment: Worth mentioning that this problem happened to me on Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 after I ran Skype for the first time and then minimized it. After it minimized, it didn't add an icon to the top right corner of the screen, so I had no way to re-open it. When I tried to re-open it from the launcher I got the above error. To fix, I installed: `sudo apt-get install sni-qt:i386`, killed the Skype process, removed the .lck file from .Skype (see answers below), and then re-opened from the launcher. The icon then appeared at the top right.

Comment: terminal -> `pkill Skype`

Comment: Funny, the same happened to me and the fixes below did not work for me. I just realized, skype was active in the status bar on top. I just had to navigate from there.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To fix the problem you will need to manually delete the lock files in your .Skype directory.

To do this, run these commands in terminal:

```
cd ~/.Skype
find ./  -name "*.lock" | xargs rm
find ./  -name "*.lck" | xargs rm
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It worked. I was having this issue and was very irritated with it. Thanks :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this again and again when this happens every couple of years :P

Answer (score 19):

If nothing works, do this:

```
cd ~
rm -rf .Skype
```

This deletes the complete Skype-Configuration and you're existing and faulty session.
.Skype will be recreated when you restart skype.

Comment: This worked for me. I had an old .Skype directory from an old installation.

Comment: Perfect... Worked like charm..

Answer (score 6):

As Donal points out you need to get rid of the lock files in the ~/.Skype dir.  I like this cmd better than Donal's merely because it's a one liner.  I'd add this as comment to Donal's answer except I can't add code blocks in comments.

```
find ~/.Skype -regex ".*\.lo?ck" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think I understand the question just fine.  I've edited my answer to provide a complete answer to the question.  I think it's a bit petty though cause I see this as an addition to Donal's answer not an answer in its own right - I just can't format it correctly as such.

Answer (score 4):

The above did not resolve it here on an Ubunto 12.04 installation.
But what helped was removing the entire ~/.Skype subdirectory  :
sudo rm -R ~/.Skype
It is remade by the Skype application the next login.

Comment: works for ubuntu 16.04